# How to use JavaScript to Require a Ratio of Completed Fields in a Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, field

I'm looking for a way to use JavaScript to require a specific ratio of fields in a form to be complete. So if I have six fields and the user has to complete any 2/6 to submit. If not then they receive an error. (The form will actually have a few different groups like this in it, so I have to be able to identify specific fields for the ratio.)

After some more research I've found something close, and realize I can count the number of a class. How would I change this to say if number of checked boxes is greater than or equal to 2, `return true`?

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
    isCountCheck("Check something");
};

function isCountCheck(helperMsg) {
    var i, len, inputs = document.form1.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
    for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) return true;
    }
    alert(helperMsg);
    return false;
}
```

UPDATE:
My final jQuery ended up like this.

```
function isCountCheck(){
    if($("input[class=crit1]:checked").length >= 4)
        return false;
    alert("Check a box");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?  What kind of elements are in this form?

Comment: Thanks David. I guess I'm really looking for an example that I could implement. In my searching, I haven't found anything close to what I'm going for. The form is multiple pages and the elements i'm needing to count are check boxes.

Comment: I've added an example that's closer to what I'm trying to do. How would you add the validation of if inputs[i].checked >=2) return true?

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer" target="_blank).

Comment: Note, however, that the code you've added into this question is not actually an answer to the question you asked. You asked how to make a determination based on an *ratio*, whereas your "final" code checks only for an absolute number of checked boxes. Being able to use that solution requires information not available in the question (e.g. the specific total number of checked boxes and the ration that you desire).

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```
var numberOfInputsCompleted = 0;
var allInputs = $(":input"); // returns all input fields on the document
var numberOfInputs = allInputs.length
allInputs.each(function () {
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    numberOfInputsCompleted = numberOfInputsCompleted  + 1;
  } 

});
```

`numberOfInputsCompleted`  would give fields completed and `numberOfInputs` would total number of input fields on the form. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have several of these ratio groups I need to setup. How could I count specific fields instead of all the fields in the form? Out of 100 fields, I need them to click 2 of the first 10 and then 4 or the next 10, etc...

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that comes to my mind: create a function that counts filled fields and returns true if the number of filled fields is enough (false otherwise). Then add it to the form as an "onsubmit" function. When the submit button is clicked the function is executed and, depending on what the function returns (true or false), the form is submitted or not.

More info about javascript form validation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp